# Как удалить файл qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

Мне нужно удалить файл либо же папку в какой либо дериктории. Как это можно сделать? Какие библиотеки подключить нужно?

Comment: Можно сделать это с помощью стандартного [std::filesystem::remove()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove)

Comment: [С помощью QT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27758573/10743113)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Qt можно использовать [QFile::remove()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#remove) и [QDir::removeRecursively()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively) для удаления файлов и папок соответственно.

```
QDir dir("mydir");
dir.removeRecursively();

QFile file("somefile.txt");
file.remove();

// или используя статический метод
QFile::remove("somefile2.txt");
```

Answer (score 4):

[`unlink()`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/unlink), [`rmdir()`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/rmdir)

Или использовать [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) из стандартной библиотеки - [`remove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove).